# Rails Paperclip, Devise insert in two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, devise, paperclip

my plan is to use Devise to register a user and giving him the opportunity to upload a picture (paperclip) while registering.
So I have users and users_pictures where user has_many :users_pictures.

I modified the usermodel like this:

```
after_create :create_users_picture

def create_users_picture
    user_id = User.last.user_id
    UsersPicture.create!(:user_id => user_id)
end
```

This was just a test to see if it's working and it actually does.
But now I need to get the fileinformation from the paperclip upload.
I already inserted the file_field to the users_view and the data is submitted correctly.
Then I tried something like:

```
def create_users_picture
    @users_picture = UsersPicture.new(@user)
    @users_picture.save
end
```

Because I thought that @user contains all necessary data ... but then I get:

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"user_firstname"=>"merrr", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xe54abbb4 @content_type="image/jpeg", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20121023-7937-1tbp5v7-0>, @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[photo]\"; filename=\"rh.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @original_filename="rh.jpeg">, "user_lastname"=>"merrr", "email"=>"merrr@asd.de", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "user_login"=>"merrr"}, "commit"=>"Sign up", "authenticity_token"=>"GRzc3Wx5mJJwBL32qjpMi24sCZdoWdRZgucldmk7Bmo=", "utf8"=>"✓"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 347ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Column 'user_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `users_pictures` (`photo_content_type`, `photo_file_name`, `photo_file_size`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)):
app/models/user.rb:36:in `create_user_profile'
```

So I can get the user_id by using User.last.user_id but how can I get the fileinformation from the picture upload ?
Do I need to get access to the POST data ? And if so, how do I do that ?
Additionally, I need to check if the user eventually tried to upload a picture ... because he does not have to.
That could be done by simply checking if there was some kind of picture data send by the form ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you actually understand that you are doing))

Good way to do that you want is to use [nested attributes for association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). 
But i don't  thin it will help you, so first of all you have to read everything [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org)

Comment: hm there are several things that I understand concerning RoR. Just that my problem seems to be a bit more specific. I am using nested routes and such; I just don't know how to get the data, that is send to "Devise::RegistrationsController#create" into my usermodel. I could also try to modify the registrations_controller but I thought that the model solution is much faster to achieve.

Comment: With nested attributes and some form modification it will be done automatically. In your case user instance doesn't know about 'photo' param in controller, ofc you can create 'photo=' method for user and you will have access to file, but it is not very good way

Comment: Hm what way would be better then ? Modifying devise controller ?

Comment: Well the thing also is, that my users_controller does not seem to be responsible for creating users anyway anymore. So I even deleted the users#create and could still usse the form. Probably because Devise-gem is handling it now ? So what if I add accepts_nested_attributes_for :users_pictures to the user model ? the user model never recieves the data, send by the form because of devise ?

Comment: I finally solved it by overriding the devise-registrations_controller.
Thank you for your advices !